# Mongoose: Variable Assignment

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

This is pretty simple so if you can find a duplicate please post it (because I can't).

So I have an object I'm receiving from the database and I want to set one of the values equal to a simple variable in the code instead of having to refer to the whole thing (note that user.info is actually an object nested inside an array).

```
let bar = user.info.foo.bar;
```

Let's just say that bar (foo.bar) is undefined but in the schema is set to a type String. I want to assign bar (foo.bar) to a string called "foo", so logically, (in my mind), I set bar equal to "foo";

```
bar = "foo";
```

When I do this and log both bar and the actual value (user.info.foo.bar) I get:

```
console.log(bar); // "foo"
console.log(user.info.foo.bar) // undefined
```

Why is it that bar gets defined but user.info.foo.bar does not even though they are both equal to each other?

There is no problem with user.info (it is defined).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a workaround

What I really wanted was to assign user.info.foo.bar the value of "foo" without actually assigning it that value directly. I can do a workaround by making "bar" a function and passing a value into it and setting user.info.foo.bar to the value;

```
const bar = (value)=>{
  user.info.foo.bar = value;
  return value
}
```

If I do it like this, I can call bar with whatever value I want and user.info.foo.bar will be equal to that value without setting it equal to that value directly (which is what I really wanted).

result:

```
console.log(bar("foo")); // "foo"
console.log(user.info.foo.bar); // "foo"
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid mutations on the original object from the DB, begin by cloning it. Solution is as follows:

```
let userInfo = {...user.info}
let bar = 'foo'
userInfo.foo.bar = bar
```

N/B: "bar" is a new memory address and therefore reassigning has no effect on "user.info" object from the database.

Comment: I want userInfo.foo.bar to be equal to "foo" without actually addressing it to the variable itself, do you think that's possible? That's what I was going for in my post.

Comment: @Bradyo Yes it is possible, I guess you mean this:
`let userInfo = {...user.info}`
`let bar = 'foo'`
`userInfo.foo.bar = bar`

Comment: For something as simple as this, this could work. But I am working with 2 variables that bar could be set to based on a condition, so this wouldn't exactly work. I guess I didn't explain my situation enough, however, I did find a solution to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you assign

```
let bar = user.info.foo.bar;
```

the value of bar is updated with the current value of user.info.foo.bar.  .
When you change the value of bar it doenst reflect because we havent added anything to modify the value of user.info.foo.bar.

Whatyou can do is to set

```
user.info.foo.bar="foo";
let bar = user.info.foo.bar;
```

Comment: I actually solved my issue with a workaround, however, thank you for your answer.